# How does Force Awakens fit into "tragedy of Darth Vader"?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, darth-vader

I read that Star Wars is "just" the tragedy of Darth Vader or Anakin Skywalker. By Episode 7 Vader is long dead. How does Force Awakens fit into this bigger picture? Is it the start of another 6 episodes about Kylo Ren?

Comment: Being so misunderstood that a guy murders children in your name is pretty tragic.

Comment: Wait what? how is this relevant

Comment: I could name plenty of reasons how it's fitting. 4 billion of them....

Comment: 4 billion what? can you use names, lol

Comment: @ThomasShera - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucasfilm#Disney_subsidiary

Comment: Is there any non-monetary reason, though?

Comment: @ThomasShera - yes. If you look at classical tragedy, many of them were generational ones - you have the Agamemnon/House of Atreus and his offspring in The Oresteia for the quintessential example (plus variations on Electra etc...). Then - going with the theme, you have Dune and Atreides (and yes they were named after the original Atreus family, which should tell you something)

Comment: @DVK could you elaborate on this mythology tie-in? I know only very basic mythology, thanks.

Comment: @ThomasShera - won't fit in the comments, but just google "The Orestreia" and look at top Wiki entries. Also, if you get interested in mythology in general as a result and want to dig, there's a sister StackExchange site called mythology.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Well, there's an [extremely silly theory about Rey and Anakin](http://www.inquisitr.com/2649390/star-wars-rey-theory-claims-to-know-who-she-is-and-it-will-floor-you/). Anyway, Lucas said that SW was all about Anakin/Vader before selling to Disney. It's safe to say SW is no linger just about Vader/Anakin.

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my question?

Answer (score 3):

The very short answer is that the new trilogy is highly unlikely to fit in with the 9 episode arc that was originally envisioned by Lucas. George Lucas' scripts, story ideas and outlines for Star Wars 7, 8 and 9 were [comprehensively rejected by Disney](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/How-George-Lucas-Star-Wars-7-Ideas-Were-Used-By-Disney-69271.html) and the new trilogy can be seen to be largely [aping the original trilogy](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/heat-vision/jj-abrams-responds-rip-criticism-853352) with the very clear intention of spawning a new franchise, one that is (presumably) going to be based around Kylo Ren's ultimate redemption at the hands of a new generation of Jedi.

Given that Vader's entire substance in the latest film was a fleeting mention that he's been a role model for Ren and a couple of throwaway scenes with his hat, Anakin's involvement in the subsequent films is peripheral at best, bordering on non-existent.

**The '*Saga of Darth Vader*' is almost certainly at an end.**

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea GL planned out the third trilogy!

Comment: @user568458 - Better? I look forward to being proven wrong... :-)

Comment: Perfect! And I also hope they come up with something better!

Comment: I always thought Star Wars was about the Skywalker family. And with Luke, Leia and Ben (Kylo) we still have 3 family members active in the new trilogy, actually more than in 1-3 which were only about Anakin becoming Vader.

Comment: @ThomasShera, glad it didn't get through either.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I'm having difficulty finding anyone officially claiming that *Star Wars* is *just* about the tragedy of Darth Vader.

While Lucas [claims](http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/george-lucas-and-the-cult-of-darth-vader-20050602) that the series is about Vader, he also claims that the original three films aren't tragedies.

> Yeah, I made a series of movies that was about one thing: Darth Vader.
>
> The first three episodes are a tragedy, and the second three go slightly goofy, but they're inspirational

However, if you believe in the tragedy of Darth Vader, *The Force Awakens* fits in very well, perhaps unintentionally.

In *[Return of the Jedi](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html)* Anakin rejoins the Light Side and becomes a Jedi again.

> Luke (to Leia) Because...there is good in him. I've felt it. He won't turn me over to 
>   the Emperor. I can save him. I can turn him back to the good side. I 
>   have to try.
>
> ...
>
> Vader: You already have, Luke. You were right about me. Tell your sister...you 
>   were right.
>
> ...
>
> He looks off to the side and sees three shimmering, smiling figures at 
>   the edge of the shadows: Ben Kenobi, Yoda, and Anakin Skywalker.

However, in *The Force Awakens*, the Vader persona he had previously thrown off [is heavily idolized by Kylo Ren](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/scifi_movies/star_wars/jj-abrams-on-why-kylo-ren-idolizes-darth-vader-in-star-a129134).

Kylo Ren misunderstood him so much that he murdered younglings (and committed various other atrocities) in his name.

> Ren: Grandfather,... I will finish what you started.

That's pretty tragic.

Answer (score 0):

While the *Saga of Anakin Skywalker* is at an end, the results of his misdeeds are still being felt around the galaxy. You may find it ironic that, for example, his behaviour is still having an effect on his family -- specifically that it would lead his grandson to the Dark Side (and the betrayal of his family).

So while Anakin's tale may be over on a personal level, the galaxy hasn't quite recovered yet.